# Grand read privilege to the user but is not allowed to grant the same privilege to another user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i am a noob and this is how far i got so far, thanks and also how would you do it if you want to allow user to grant the same privilege to another user.

```
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE_NAME.* TO USER;
```

Comment: Have you tried the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) already?

Comment: @AndriyM i have already solved the issue, thanks

Comment: Please: either provide the solution, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to add

```
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

at the end of grant command line.
e.g.
if i wanted to grant select privilege (+ allow user to grant the same privilege to another user), to a user called user1 for table EMPLOYEE. Here would a an appropriate command

```
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASENAME.EMPLOYEE TO USER1  WITH GRANT OPTION;
```